# How do I make a program insert a new line every time it finds a space (or whitespace) within a string (in java)?

Tags: java

I'm a first year IT student and we recently had an activity that asks the programmer to create a program that will accept a sentence or a phrase, then detect if there is a space in that string and add a newline in between words that have a space after it.

For clarification, here's what the prompt should look like:
Enter a sentence or phrase: I am a student

then the output would be:
I
am
a
student

I tried to actually finish the code, but I was hit by a roadblock and got stuck. Here's my attempt though:

```
import java.util.*;
public class NumTwo{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String phr;

        System.out.print("Enter a phrase: ");
        phr = in.nextLine();

        if(phr.contains(" ")){
            System.out.print(phr + "\n");
        }
        else{

        }
    }
}
```

any comments to what i might have done wrong will be very much appreciated

EDIT:
I tried using sir Christoph Dahlen's solution which was to use String.replace, and it worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: You can either use [String.replace(char,char)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)) and replace every "space"-character by a "newline" character or [String.replaceAll(String,String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)). The later would use a regular expression of "\s+" and replace every matching occurence with the newline mark.

Comment: `phr = phr.replaceAll("\\s+", System.lineSeaparator());`.

Answer (score -1):

You are currently checking weither the input line contains any spaces at all, but you have to react to every space instead.

One way would be to split `phr` by spaces and concatenating it with newlines.

```java
String result = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), phr.split(" "))
```